# How to find the network address of a given subnet?

Tags: ipv6, subnet

I have to make 256 subnets in a given ip address 2001:1001:0ff0::/48 and in addition I need to find the ip addresses for the 2nd, 48th and 224th subnet.

I need to know if there is a formula to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are on a Q&A forum about software programming, here is the formula included in a simple program (bash/zsh shell script):

```
for subnet in {0..255}
do
  echo 2001:1001:0ff0:$(printf "%02x00" $subnet)::/$(echo 48 - $(echo 'l(256)/l(2)' | bc -l) / 1 | bc)
done
```

To get the 2nd, 48th and 224th subnets, use this program and formula:

```
for subnet in 1 47 223
do
  echo 2001:1001:0ff0:$(printf "%02x00" $subnet)::/$(echo 48 - $(echo 'l(256)/l(2)' | bc -l) / 1 | bc)
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

please consider the documentation of IPv6 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1883. You can find a formula and description on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address